# best way to store and retrieve an Asset

Tags: assets, java-sdk

Does anybody know best way to store an Asset descriptor once it has been created with `Asset.createNonNativeAsset(currencyName, issuingKeys);`? How do we store it and retrieve the reference when we need for instance to transfer from that asset and create trustlines?

I tried with

`Asset asset = new AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum4("WOW", issuingKeys);`

But hashcode etc are different.

Answer (score 2):

What SDK are you using? Java, C#?

First of all, you are creating them differently. In the first case with a static method, in the second – with class constructor. I bet that the static method returns `AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum4` casted to an abstract parent class, something like `AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum`.

In general, asset descriptor should be identical and work without any problems in both cases, of course if the asset `code` and `issuer` are the same in both calls. So try to check this in the first place. And do not forget about the case. `"WOW"` and `"WoW"` will return different hashcodes.